# ./configure bash:No such file or directory

Tags: 12.04

I have been trying to configure the above python module but getting the thread as "No such file or directory"

```
$ cd Desktop
$ tar -zxvf dm.xmlsec.binding.1.0b3.tar.gz
$ cd dm.xmlsec.binding.1.0b3
$ ./configure
bash:No such file or directory
```

please help me out!

Comment: Is there a README file? Because the error is very straigtforward: there either is no file called configure, or the x flag has not been set. If its the second, you should try `chmod +x configure`. But my advaice is to read the README first.

Answer (score 0):

So, this mean that there is no `configure` file: `No such file or directory`.

You should try:

```
chmod +x setup.py
./setup.py
```

instead of `./configure`.

Answer (score 0):

Configure is mostly used in packages using the autoconf/automake build system. Since you are installing a python module, a different build system is used. The relevant command for you is

```
python setup.py
```

To install system wide, you might need to run it with sudo.

You might need to install the python-setuptools package first if it isn't installed yet, and also some other prerequisite packages, about which you should be informed by the setup script.